# Read eclipse .class source code for dependent plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin, dependencies

I'm working on an Eclipse plug-in, and I have some .jar files under "Plug-in Dependencies". But, I'm getting confused why the .class files under some .jar files can be opened, and I can see the code, and others give me "Class File Editor - Source Not Found". Bellow are links of two examples:

1. http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadorgeclipseecfdocshare210v201002191253jar.htm which has org.eclipse.docshare. This .jar I get the above error when I try to open it.
2. http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadorgeclipseecf31300v201105312218jar.htm, which I can easily open and see the source code

Can anyone clarifies that ?!!!

Answer (score 0):

Normally, this is because you have source code associated with the jar file. To associate the source code with the library, in the Java Build Path dialog, on the Libraries tab, open the jar and you will find four additional sub-items. The first is the Source attachment, and that is where you specify the source code.

You can do this with the JRE or any User Libraries as well.

Comment: The Source Attachment refers to the one that is already in Eclipse plugins folder. Also, I assured the .jar has the source code. But, still it doesn't work, and I can't see the attachment

Comment: If the source attachment refers to the .jar file in the Eclipse plugins folder, it likely does not have the source. That is normally the binary distribution. Normally the source is a separate jar or a directory.